# PHPStorm Refactoring - Reference Change Isn't Recognized When Moving PHP Files?

Tags: phpstorm

I have the following reference in some of my PHP files:

```
require_once "../folder/subfolderone/referencedFile.php";
```

When I move the above file to a different folder at

```
../folder/subfoldertwo/referencedFile.php
```

and check the search for references option when moving the file, the `require_once` references in my other files are not changed.

How do I get PHPStorm to recognize the file move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware it is still not supported.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4439 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

---

**P.S.**
If this code is yours and it is new (not some old project) -- consider using autoloading functionality for your classes (be it writing your own simple autoloader or using composer autoloader for that) -- especially if it's namespaced code.